# Hibernate mapping - compile error

Tags: oracle, hibernate

I get a compile error from eclipse with this hibernate query. Below is the code and the picture of eclipse compile error

```
<sql-query name="endDateChecker">
<return-scalar column="PId" type="java.lang.Long"/>
            select
            pid as PId
            from
            info
            where
            end_date < trunc(sysdate)
 </sql-query>
```

http://i34.tinypic.com/rrtq36.png -> my compile error picture

What did I do wrong, how do I fix it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the `< trunc(sysdate)` part. Specifically, `<` character causes an error. Either wrap your SQL query in CDATA section:

```
<![CDATA[select ... where end_date < trunc(sysdate) ]]>
```

or escape `<` with `&lt;`.